# Ti.Media.takeScreenshot -Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-mobile

I am getting this error when trying to take screenshot..i can able to take the screen but even simultaneously getting this error..

Here is my code...

```
sharebutton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(event) {
        //scrollView.toImage();
        var filenameforscreenshot = "screenshot" + new Date().getDate()+".jpg";
        Ti.API.info('cam filename-' + filenameforscreenshot);
        var scrnImage = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, filenameforscreenshot);
        scrnImage.write(event.media);
        Ti.App.Properties.setString("screenshotcapture", scrnImage.nativePath);
    });
    var createnewWindow = require('ui/sharestay');
    new createnewWindow(my_id, '').open();
    win.close();
});
```

and the error in console...

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,5081] - Message: Uncaught Error:  Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,5081] - Source: ).open(),o.close()}),u.addEventListener("click",function(){Ti.Media.takeScreen
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ui/stay_listexpand.js:1: Uncaught Error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Plz help im stuck in this for more than a day...

Comment: Plz do comment if this if some more information is needed...